# Query populated document with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I have following **mongodb/mongoose** data model::

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
     name: String
   , roles: [] // admin or client
   /* others object */
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
    title: String
    , user: {
         type: Schema.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Review', ReviewSchema);
```

Now I want to get all **review** where user's role is **admin**. I have tried the following way:

```
Review
  .find( { 'user.roles': 'admin' } )
  .populate('user')
  .exec(function(err, review) {
     console.log("review : ", review); // null
  });
```

**NB:** `"mongoose": "^4.2.9",`

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not specify which version of mongoose you are using. The current documentation says to use `Schema.Types.ObjectId`, not `Schema.ObjectId`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope, this code may be solved your problem

```
Review.find()
.populate('user', null, { roles:"admin" })
.exec(function (err, review) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json(err);
    }else {
        var review = review.filter(function (review) {
                    return review.user !== null;
                 }).pop();
       console.log(review);          
       res.json(review);
   }
});
```